# Access Cross Table with editable checkbox

Tags: sql, ms-access

At first, let me thank you and similar communities, because a week ago I had almost no knowledge of Access, and now I have complete database with forms that does (almost) all I need to. I am slightly stuck on the last step, and trying to google for answer, I think my limited experience doesn't allow me to fully understand the answers and apply them in my specific case.

To the question.

Long story short, I want to make a tool to help scoping regression tests. We have many test cases and many configurations to run them on. I already have everything to generate test cases automatically out of many options and choose the applicable, then I do the same for the configs - I generate all combinations and select ones appropriate and in scope.

Ultimately I arrive at 3 tables -> 
TestCasesAll
TestConfigs (both have a InScope Yes/No field)
TestConfigScope

TestConfigScope contains fields:

TestCase -> reference to testCasesAll table

TestConfig -> reference to TestConfigs table

InScope -> well, to be selected if it is in scope for this run on this config

In our organisation we are used to Cross Table, and it does seem like the most human readable format to play with it. I would like to have ultimately a form with all the TestConfigs InScope=True as Columns, all test cases as columns, and a checkbox on the cross. When there is no record in TestConfigScope, or the record has value InScope = False, this checkbox should be unchecked. Checking this box should add a record - if not yet existing, and marking it as in scope.

Is that even possible without magic? :)

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: Crosstabs are not editable. You have to do some fancy stuff to get your idea to work.

Comment: Hi there. 
Indeed, I know that crosstab report is not editable, I already came across that one before. 

I did not try a pivot sql command, but the way it looks, I guess it's going to be the same issue.

That's why, I am asking for help :)

If there is no easier way, maybe I should go on and have some VBA to automatically (re)populate form with the appropriate headers?

Comment: Unfortunately, all the images in this have died, but it may give you some ideas http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating

Comment: @Fionnuala thanks for the link. Although, I find it difficult to understand without the screenshots. As mentioned, I'm a newb...

I will try to give it some more thought, maybe I will come up with something :)

Comment: That would be great! How to do this? I don't see an option to send private messages, and i prefer to avoid posting e-mail address in the open...